# Ubuntu seems to not free RAM memory

Tags: ram, swap, memory-usage, memory-leak

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 in a laptop with 12 GB of RAM.  When I start the system, everything is fast and responsive, and memory usage is 1.5 - 2 GB.

Then if I start resource-intensive programs, like Android studio with an emulator, about 5 GB of ram is used, but everything still runs quickly and smoothly.  However,  after 2-3 hours of work with the same opened applications, the memory becomes almost full, the system uses the swap file, and and everything get very slow.  Even after closing all programs, the system operation remains slow.

Some of my friends have the same issue with apps like VMware and other resource-intensive programs.

It appears that RAM is not being released under such operations.  Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: Memory-not-released usually is called a *memory leak*, and is considered a bug. Please file a bug report with the appropriate upstream project with sufficient detail for them to duplicate the *exact* issue or leak.

Comment: i don't think memory leakage is happening because if i kill the process memory is still full

Comment: To me, that seems like confirmation that it IS a leak of some kind.

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* that you have killed all the processes using large amounts of memory? Please, investigate your system with tools like `htop` to find were the memory has gone. :)